# Font resets when generating PDF from HTML using chromium pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, chromium

I am generating a PDF using the chromium pdf plugin, which so far is working properly, except my font resets after generating a pdf:
[image]

[image]

I've tried using the @font-face with custom fonts, as well as simply using @import with a google web font:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hanalei&display=swap');
```

Is there a certain way I have to use @font-face, or general embedding when working with pdf/chromium pdf in particular?

It seems whatever I change on my front-end, it doesn't affect the font on the PDF whatsoever, but changing layout formatting works properly.

Comment: Not sure, but tried to remove that swap? Swap shows any font until webfont ist loaded. Try something else like here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-displayDisplay Look hat the url parameter at the end of that font url.

Comment: @SaschaGrindau hey! Your link seems dead, but I tried removing '&display=swap', and the same result persists

Comment: Damn autocorrection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display

Comment: If that does not help, watch: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/422

Comment: @SaschaGrindau I understand what's happening in the puppeteer thread, but fail to find a way to perform the same action for the chromium pdf plugin, I'll keep digging